# how compressed can I get a heightmap?

Tags: compression, heightmap

I've been playing around with simple terrain generation ( diamond square alogorithm ) and I got to thinking about how large I can practically do it.

If I wanted to generate a continent, then a `1000 by 1000 km` square would be big enough, but if I also wanted high resolution it quickly results in humongous file sizes. `1000 by 1000 km = 1` million square km, if I store a point for every meter, then every square km is a million square meters.

If I use unsigned shorts ( max altitude of 10,000 meters ) and I do my math right, that's 2TB of data. Of course I couldn't store it all in RAM at once, but even with HDD space getting cheaper everyday, a 2TB heightmap is not practical.

I got to thinking about compressing the data, but I've never done compression before, and have no clue how far I could shrink it down, if it goes from 2 to `1.9 TB`, it wouldn't be worth it. What compression methods work best without loss of data?

I'm willing to reduce the size and resolution of the heightmap, but I'd like to make it as large as practical.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do depends a lot on your needs. If you don't need all geometrical data all the time and can spare a lot of CPU time, as little as a couple of bytes for your random seed will suffice to reliably regenerate the full terrain. You could also  go ahead and divide your continent into patches and store a seed for each patch. That way you can recreate smaller bits of the continent reliably without having to go through the expense of creating the whole continent each time you only need a fraction of the geometry.